# How to download React components for offline use

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-framework, offlineapps, virtual-dom

Is there a way to download React components and also have full javascript functionality?  For example, a table component that still can be sorted without a network connection.   Offline-first seems to be a possible solution but doesn't exactly specify how to deal with individual meeting.  Another possibility is converting the React application to pure javascript that can be run on the client side.  But, essentially isn't that what the React compiling does anyway?

Comment: in index file serviceWorker.register(); and read about service Workers

Comment: Is there another way besides using offline-first pwa paradigm?

Comment: i don't thinks so... for this reason this tools are created.

Comment: Can't you just save the page with ctrl+s and reopen it in a browser locally?  Obviously you may have no connectivity.

Comment: It's called Progressive Web App Here you can find detailed Progressive Web Apps Training from Google. It includes service workers and other features.
https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa
Here is not so detailed but good explanation of PWA
https://web.dev/progressive-web-apps/

Comment: It has to have the same functionality with "data".  That's the catch.

Comment: I think the PWA is a definite option

Comment: Problem is not PWA or pure Js or on network or off network. Problem is data source, where is the data coming from and how it persists. Its not one but two of them combined together. Now if its AJAA call that gets the data and then stores it on some variable while browser window is open then forget about it. Because the moment browser window closes data is gone. PWA or no PWA

Comment: what you need to incorporate is local storage (indexdb would be god way forward) ....app->check if db is present => if not make AJAx call to get db => if present or when ajax successful run code on db, no need to touch network again unless client server communication required.  .

Comment: you have service worker which saves the Js app code  on cache first basis -> you are off line or turned computer after so many hours run webpage -> service worker kicks app code in action -> which checks indexdb which would be present and do what ever you need to do......key word persistent data nor persistent files. https://medium.com/jspoint/indexeddb-your-second-step-towards-progressive-web-apps-pwa-dcbcd6cc2076